# Buscar dos coincidencias en un campo

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla con dos campos y quiero sacar las coincidencias en otro campo de otra tabla. Un campo es el inicio y el otro el final del mismo campo.

**Tabla1**

- `CampoA` puede terminar o no con `_`
- `CampoB` siempre empieza con `_`

Por ejemplo:

```
CampoA     CampoB    CampoC
-------------------------------
HOLA_      _ADIOS     1
HOLA       _BYE       2
HOLA       _ADIOS     3
```

---

**Tabla2**

```
CampoAB  
---------------------------
HOLA_1S_ADIOS
HOLA_ADIOS
HOLA_BYE
```

El resultado que necesito sería:

```
CampoAB        CampoC
-------------------------------
HOLA_ADIOS       1 
HOLA_1S_ADIOS    2
HOLA_BYE         3
```

Lo mas sencillo, buscar con likes no funciona, porque cuando es HOLA, también es HOLA_

He probado a crear el string para buscar por like "like concat(campo1,"*\",campo2). Con regexp he buscado sacar los holas con y sin "*" para buscar en dos fases.

Estoy probando de diferentes formas, al final cuanto mas funciones uso mas lento se vuelve la búsqueda. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, o decirme cual es la mejor forma.

Gracias

Comment: Hola, intentan explicarlo mejor porque no se entiende que es lo que buscas, que falla, como se relacionan los campos, etc...

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. He editado la pregunta, porque no se entendía nada como lo estabas planteado. Revisa y confirma que los datos **existen** así en tus tablas. No uses las comillas ni cosas de esas, en las preguntas es mejor que pongas los datos como existen realmente, y simulando la forma en que se presentan en las tablas, de lo contrario es muy difícil entender la situación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de sacar los datos, si he entendido correctamente lo que quieres, puede ser con un `JOIN` que utilice como condición el `like` para ambos campos:

```
SELECT T2.CampoAB, T1.CampoC
FROM Tabla2 T2 
JOIN Tabla1 T1 ON T2.CampoAB LIKE CONCAT(T1.CampoA, '%') AND T2.CampoAB LIKE CONCAT('%' + T1.CampoB)
```

En este caso si un mismo `CampoAB` cumple las condiciones de por ejemplo dos casos de la `Tabla1`, te sacará dos resultados con sus correspondientes valores de `CampoC`, lo cual está bien si te interesan todos los posibles resultados. Para restringir más este resultado sería necesario conocer cuáles son los criterios que aplicarías.
Espero que te sirva.

Edición: coincidencias excluyentes, si el carácter especial '_' está incluido en la cadena final no esté en la inicial, es decir, que no puede formar parte de ambos campos.
En este caso buscamos primero con la condición de que cumplan el campo final y después preguntamos si lo que queda a la izquierda de este campo cumple el criterio del campo inicial.

```
SELECT T2.CampoAB, T1.CampoC
FROM Tabla2 T2 
JOIN Tabla1 T1 ON T2.CampoAB LIKE CONCAT('%' + T1.CampoB)
AND LEFT(T2.CampoAB, (INSTR(T2.CampoAB,T1.CampoB)-1)) LIKE CONCAT(T1.CampoA, '%')
```

Cual de los campos manda sobre el otro, es decir, cual es la primera condición es algo que dependerá del diseño.

Comment: Muchas gracias Carmen.  Tu solución la probé, en el caso del final funciona, pero en el inicio del campo, al haber dos posibilidades, con y sin "_" al final, cuando busco HOLA, me sale HOLA y HOLA_  Y necesito que sea exacto, HOLA_ADIOS en el primer caso y HOLA_1S_ADIOS en el segundo caso.

Comment: He editado la pregunta para que los campos sean excluyentes, si he entendido bien lo que necesitas, de todas maneras no me cuadran los resultados que has modificado en la pregunta ¿ej. HOLA_ADIOS no sería 3 en lugar de 1, HOLA_BYE 2 y HOLA_1S_ADIOS 1?